# Do functions attached to the prototype property not have closure

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how I can add methods to a constructor after I have created it.
In my code below, I cannot use Person's prototype property to add a new public method which has access to Person's vars. (Do the functions attached to the prototype property not close over the vars in the main function).
Unlike the first way, the second way works - Person 2. seems like these are called privileged methods -http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html.

```
function Person(name, age){}
Person.prototype.details = function(){ 
    return "name: "+name+", age: "+age;
};

function Person2(name, age){
 this.details = function(){ 
    return "name: "+name+", age: "+age;};
}

var per1 = new Person("jim", 22);
var per2 = new Person2("jack", 28);

per1.details();
//=> ReferenceError: age is not defined
per2.details();
//=> "name: jack, age: 28"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not, the function was declared in a scope, different to the scope where the arguments/variables were declared, so JS wouldn't know which variables you're on about. Suppose you had a second closure, or better (well, worse actually) yet: a global variable called `name`. Which one would JS pick?

Here's an example for you:

```
function MyObject(name)
{
    var localVar = 'foobar';
    this.evilMethod = (function(localVar)
    {
        return function()
        {
            console.log('localVar = '+localVar);//=== name
        };
    })(name);
    this.badMethod = function()
    {
        console.log('localVar = '+ localVar);// === 'foobar'
    };
}
var name = 'Global Name';
var anotherClosure = (function(name)
{
    var localVar = name.toLowerCase();
    return function()
    {
        console.log(name);
        console.log(localVar);
    }
})('Bobby');
MyObject.prototype.closureVars = function()
{
    console.log(name);//Global name
    console.log(localVar);//undefined
};
```

Now first off: this is terrible code, but you get the point: you can have hundreds of variables with the same name, which one JS has to use, might not always be clear.

Giving prototypes access to instance closure variables has other implications, too: you could, for instance change their values, which defeats the point of having a closure in the first place. 
But the biggest problem *by a country mile* would be: multiple instances! If you create a constructor, odds are you're going to instantiate more than 1 object with it. **How would that work, if they all share the same prototype?**

Just assign the arguments/variables you want to access in the prototype to a property, like FishBasketGordo's example does

Comment: Sorry for the rant, just came home from work, and had a bit of a fight :)

Answer (score 4):

No, they do not have closure over the constructor functions vars. They are in a different scope.

```
// This function is in one scope.
function Person(name, age) {
}

// This statement is in the parent scope, which 
// doesn't have access to child scopes.
Person.prototype.details = function(){ 
    return "name: "+name+", age: "+age;
};
```

That's the way that "public" functions work in JavaScript. You could make `details` a privileged function by defining it within the constructor:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.details = function() { 
        return "name: "+name+", age: "+age;
    };
}
```

Of course, that means that each instance of `Person` gets it's own copy of the `details` function.

You could also, as @Chuck suggests, make `name` and `age` public members, in which you would have access to them in a prototype function:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.details = function(){ 
    return "name: " + this.name + ", age: " + this.age;
};
```

Comment: You could also assign `this.name` and `this.age` in the constructor.

Comment: @Chuck: i did not want to do that cause, i wanted name and age to be private (essentially creating an immutable Person object)

Comment: If that's the case @deepak, then you should use a privileged method.

Answer (score 1):

No. Typically you would either use the second approach, or set `this._name = name;` in the constructor and reference it that way in the other method.